# JPEGs showing shifted colors in certain applications

Tags: nvidia, firefox, colors, gimp, color-management

I am running Kubuntu 19.10 with a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card with the v435 drivers.

After editing some photos in Darktable, I have found out that sometimes certain applications show colors in photos more vibrant than others. By comparing some edited photos by displaying them on a second device, I have found out, that graphical programs like Gimp or Darktable show the colors correctly (= the same way as my Android phone), but other applications sometimes really mess up the color balance, mostly by adding contrast and making them more red.

In this following screenshot I have opened the same JPEG file in Firefox, Gwenview and Gimp. Gwenview shows the colors too bright and contrasty, Gimp and Firefox show the colors more toned down.

[image]

In this second screenshot you can see Firefox making the image too red, opposed to Gimp on the right (which I believe to display the colors correctly.)

[image]

I suspect it might be caused by different ways the image is decoded, I suspect that some applications use CPU to decode them and other use the graphics card. But this is just my wild, uneducated guess.

Does anyone have an idea, how to make Firefox and other applications show the images correctly?

**Edit:** I have managed to temporarily fix the colors by downgrading the nvidia drivers to the version 430. I will be happy for suggestions how to achieve correct colors in the latest available driver version.

**Edit:** As requested, [here is a link to an original file](https://files.janjaromirhorak.cz/color-test.jpg), that shows different colors in Gimp and Firefox with the v435 drivers. With the v430 the photo looks the same in all tested programs.

Comment: Likely a matter of a color profile or non-standard gamma encoded in the image and not taken in account in some apps. Can you share the image (on a site that won't recompress it...)?

Comment: I will provide a sample, I just have to create a new image that I can share for privacy reasons.

Comment: @xenoid I have edited the question to include a link to an image, that looks different in different programs. I had to reinstall the drivers back to 435 to test this, sorry for the delay.

Comment: You image has an embedded color profile. Try with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r0IW.jpg) that has a funky color profile that makes colors look seriously out of whack when the color profile is not used.